# clearTimeout does not work in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout, cleartimeout

I tried to use clearTimeout to escape from the recursive setTimeout function.

But it doesn´t work properly, so I just returned it using if function.

```
   word.move = () => {
    if (test >= 10) {
      console.log(wodrd.move);
      //clearTimeout(word.move);
      return;
    }
    test++;
    console.log(test);
    word.node.style.top = `${test}px`;
    setTimeout(word.move, speed);
  };
```

How could it be stopped by using clearTimeout?

Comment: setTimeout returns an id, which you have to pass to clearTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` returns a value that you need to save, in order to pass to `clearTimeout` later.

```
let wordMoveTimeout;

word.move = () => {
  if (test >= 10) {
    clearTimeout(wordMoveTimeout);
    return;
  }

  // other logic here...

  wordMoveTimeout = setTimeout(word.move, speed);
}
```

Read the [documentation on how to use setTimeout here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!